# Can a directive inherit a ng-click from his parent scope?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to work with ng-view directive and I want to batter understand the parameters of my scope and controller.

my web page has a static part and inside of it the ng-view directive like so:

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="controller">
  <a href="" ng-click="act()" ng-init="search='search'">search >></a> 
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Then I am using my .config to route to my requested page "search".

Now I know that the directive inherits the scope above him and I can see it by approaching to $scope.search variable.

My question is why can't I grab the ng-click event as well?

```
// search controller

var print = $scope.search;   // all good

$scope.act = function() {
    console.log("grabed");
}
```

can someone explain why the ng-click does not passed to the directive, and how can I make it happen?

Thank you

Comment: Because `$scope` on the search controller is child scope of `controller` where you declared `ng-click="act()"`.

Comment: can you tell me how to make it work ?